# How do I implement bubble notifications in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, public-activity

I already have a feed with the public_activity gem . However, I want to have a facebook-like on-site notification system where the user can see a number in red background, representing the new notifications concerning him. 
I have never implemented such a thing and I am not sure how to go about it.

Most answers about Rails notifications will recommend using Mailboxer, public_activity, and any other messaging gem but nothing about the dynamic real-time facebook like notification that easily alarms you of the new notifications with the number and links.
Thanks for your help !!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [polling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes) with a JS library like jQuery. There is another good [example](http://thelazylog.com/long-polling-with-puma-rails-4-and-server-sent-events/) that can be followed.

The main focus would be making an ajax request after a specific time and check for the results and repeat the process.